# Getting and error “Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found” in oomp installer

Tags: eclipse, oomph

```
Calculating requirements and dependencies.
Cannot complete the request.  Generating details.
ERROR: org.eclipse.pde.core code=0 Problems occurred while resolving the target contents
  at org.eclipse.oomph.util.OomphPlugin.coreException(OomphPlugin.java:280)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.util.pde.TargetPlatformUtil.activateTargetDefinition(TargetPlatformUtil.java:151)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.targlets.internal.core.TargletContainer.forceUpdate(TargletContainer.java:787)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.targlets.impl.TargletTaskImpl$4.run(TargletTaskImpl.java:1167)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.util.pde.TargetPlatformUtil.runWithTargetPlatformService(TargetPlatformUtil.java:120)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.targlets.impl.TargletTaskImpl.perform(TargletTaskImpl.java:1033)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3332)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.access$1(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3275)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer$WorkspaceUtil$1.run(SetupTaskPerformer.java:4502)
  at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2240)
  at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2267)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer$WorkspaceUtil.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:4496)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer$WorkspaceUtil.access$0(SetupTaskPerformer.java:4494)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3266)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3241)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3141)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.wizards.ProgressPage$9.run(ProgressPage.java:575)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.wizards.ProgressPage$11$1.run(ProgressPage.java:701)
  at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
  ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director code=10053 Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
    ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director code=0 Software being installed: artificial_root 1.0.0.v1526038212974
    ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director code=0 Missing requirement: Utils classes for JUnit tests 2.1.100.201803121156 (org.eclipse.papyrus.junit.utils 2.1.100.201803121156) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.papyrus.uml.tools [4.0.0,5.0.0)' but it could not be found
    ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director code=1 Cannot satisfy dependency:
      ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director code=0 From: artificial_root 1.0.0.v1526038212974
      ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director code=0 To: org.eclipse.papyrus.junit.utils 0.0.0

Took 66 seconds.
There are failed tasks.
```

Comment: One simple thing to do is simply try again, in case there was some transient problem during the install. Although their situation was not identical to yours, [a user on an Eclipse forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1086661/) reported that trying again worked for them. Can't hurt to try...

Comment: sir i have tried 20 times but same problem persists

Comment: OK. Could you please update you post with [1] The version of Eclipse that you are using. [2] What you were trying to install, and what you did to install it.

Comment: i am currently using eclipse oxygen.i am trying to install eclipse dev environment using the link https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Installer
i have to setup papyrus dev environemnt, i am referring the doc https://wiki.eclipse.org/Papyrus-RT/Developer/Developer_Guide/DevEnv 
it works fine toill step 21 in above link but afterwards it fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the setup using your link and got exactly the same stack trace and underlying error as you.

Someone else also encountered that same underlying problem (i.e. *"...requires 'bundle org.eclipse.papyrus.uml.tools [4.0.0,5.0.0)' but it could not be found"*) and [raised it on Eclipse's Papyrus-RT forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1085752&goto=1781437&#msg_1781437).

The response to their problem, dated 2/12/18, was:

> **If you want the developer environment, unfortunately at this moment the Oomph setup model is broken because of some issues related to the
>   target platform and its dependencies to the base Papyrus.  We are
>   trying to fix them but we don't know when it will be fixed.**
>
> In the meantime, I'm trying to write down instructions on setting up
>   the environment manually, but it is not easy, and it will take some
>   time.
>
> But I'll post a note here when the instructions are available in the
>   wiki.

So it looks like it's not currently possible to perform the Oomph setup using Oxygen. Note that all of the screen shots in the documentation you linked to are from Mars and Neon, using a much earlier release of Java 8 from 2016.

Comment: yes i was thinking the same.it was too generous of you to go ahead and try the setup, m so grateful to you,if u dont mind may i ask,do u have any idea on papyrus, i want to integrate it to my rcp application,here is the link to my requirement 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50147634/how-can-i-integrate-papyrus-plugin-in-my-rcp-application-i-want-to-access-papyr